# c# localization assembly (*.resources)

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I work in a company and our app is localizable, but we have encountered a problem.

Original language is PL and we have EN translation in satellite assemblies (*.resource files translated using Sisulizer).

When we run our app without changing language on english OS, our app is translated to EN in some places and I can't find why.

When we have 'original' PL language it should stay PL and not look for any satellite assemblies to translate itself for OS language. We have CurrentUICulture set to pl-PL but when I run Assembly Binding Log Viewer it shows that one of dll's is looking for *.resources file with culture=en.

More to say, this dll is Base class dll.
BaseForms is subproject holding all base forms and it's built as dll. This dll is looking for *.resources in log.
ourAppName is another subproject that is built as exe and it has some forms that derives from BaseForms, f.e. Main Form.

any tips, please?

Comment: Sorry I had to edit. I was finding hard to read all that bunch of text

Comment: As far as I remember, the language that is used to determine what strings are extracted from resources depends on the thread's culture which is equal to OS's by default. Probably in your program you override the culture to match the chosen language but someone  forgot  to set it in some places of you app. That can explain  why on EN OS you get English in some places of your app but not in the others.

Comment: looks like BaseForms class has problems with translation but in Program.cs Main() I see that someone added System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pl");

Comment: @grahoo but is `BaseForms` accessed from the same thread as `Main()`? [Read here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): default culture would be applied to new threads if not explicitly set otherwise. You may want to override default culture (I guess).

Comment: Thanks for a tip, I will check if it helps

edit. found that DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture  is in Framework 4.5 and we use 4.0 and want to stay with 4.0 currently... as I know

Comment: Is there any tool that I can use for checking culture in all threads used by app?

Comment: @grahoo except for your own hands and lots of debug, none that I know of ^-) also you may put @ nickname at the beggining of you comments, it would help ppl notice that you posted something

Answer (score 0):

There are several places where to set the culture. For a WPF application, you can use:

```
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern ushort SetThreadUILanguage(ushort _languageId);

public static void SetLanguage(string uiLanguage)
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(uiLanguage);
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(uiLanguage);
    SetThreadUILanguage((ushort) Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.LCID);
    FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FrameworkElement), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.IetfLanguageTag)));
}
```

Note that the last line is for WPF only, and `DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture` requires C#5 (if you use an earlier version of the framework, you have to set the culture for every thread individually).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that some other part of you application (might even be a library that you uses) sets the CurrentUICulture to Enhlish on runtime. I have see this happening few times. Every single time some library code has changed the CurrentUICulture. Try to locate the moment when this happens either by debugging or figuring out from the the strings that appear in English.